# How does one know which operations can be done on a resource using the AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk

I understand you can use the AWS API Gateway to allow developers to create applications that interact with AWS backend services (e.g. DynamoDB).

The basic flow is:

1. Create the resource (e.g. DynamoDB table)
2. Create a Lambda function
3. Create an HTTP API
4. Create Routes
5. Create an integration
6. Attach integration to routes

[image]

But what are the options for the API? What kind of operations can be done on DynamoDB (or whatever resource you’re working with)?

Usually when a REST API is available through a Gateway there is a set of endpoints, so the developers know what they can build with the API. Like Swagger Documentation.

It would be great to know all the things that can be done via API to DynamoDB, S3, Cloudwatch, etc. is there a master list somewhere?

Or is the idea that you can do anything inside the Lambda function that is supported by the `aws-sdk`?

In that case, is there a list of available options for the `aws-sdk`?

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: Yes, you can do anything (or nothing or a mix of those) in your lambda and it is up to you wether or not your lambda behaves like a REST api and has a openapi spec file or not. Nothing in the API Gateway forces you to have it but you may want to have it.

Comment: Note that you can also potentially [use Amazon API Gateway as a proxy for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) (and other AWS services).

Comment: In short, you can do anything in the lambda function. Connect to services like DynamoDb, SNS, or SES to perform tasks. See SDK docs, Java: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html and JS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ I notice the JavaScript API, calling through the browser, doesn’t use lambda. In this case, how would one know what services and operations are possible (since these would now be preset…since no lambda)?

Comment: @jarmod I thought this was how it’s always done. So you don’t have to use the API Gateway? You can use the API endpoints directly?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. A client that wants to interact with DynamoDB typically has 3 options: 1) include AWS SDK within the client and client makes request directly to the DynamoDB service, 2) client makes API Gateway request which triggers a Lambda function which interacts with DynamoDB and 3) client makes API Gateway request and API Gateway proxies request to DynamoDB. Each has its pluses and minuses wrt auth and  feature set. #2 is the most common in practice afaik.

Comment: Of course you can and should call the API endpoints directly if you want to directly interact with an AWS service. The question is wether or not the calling party has the right permissions and wether or not you want to expose the internal resources / structure. Note that this is once again unrelated to AWS but a general web service question: do you grant the client SELECT permission on the database? Probably not, you perform the SELECT in your API and send the output along. But if you read an image or some other static data chances are you do NOT need an API between.

Comment: It all depends on the type of client, what kind of interactions, what kind of API, what abstraction, what usecase, etc. This is not answerable in general.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. I thought the API Gateway was the only option to interact with AWS services via REST. Now I see there are 3 options. I am still unclear what advantage #3 has over #2.

Comment: Not sure where the downvote came from. As for #2 vs. #3, the blog post has a list of possible reasons to consider the proxy route (search for "a few great reasons to do so"). It's rare, in my opinion, however given how flexible the Lambda-based option is but for a simple, constrained use case the proxy option might make sense. I see it used more for proxying S3 and IAM, tbh.